# Representation in matrix form

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

How can I represent the following equation in matrix form?

$$|a x + b y| \leq k_1$$
$$|c x + d y| \leq k_2$$

where a, b, c and d are complex. I am confused with the absolute sign since its not a linear operator. I could use Cauchy Schwarz inequality but that would not exactly fulfill the inequality conditions.

Edit: $x, y, k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Why do you want this represented in matrix form?  Also, it's worth mentioning that $(a_1\, a_2)\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2\end{pmatrix} = a_1b_1+a_2b_2$, if this counts as "matrix form".

Comment: I am trying to solve an optimization problem that requires a form like:

$$A b \leq k$$ where A is a matrix and $b = [x \; y]^T$

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ complex numbers (in this case, a better notation would be $z_1$ and $z_2$) or are they the real and imaginary parts of a complex number ?

Comment: x and y are real.